# angular - changing the icon colour when clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

I currently have a table which displays list of items. Each item has an icon next to it. What I would like to do is to click on them icon and it will changes its colour. Right now, when I click on any of the icons, it will only change the colour of the first icon.

```
<table class="table table-borderless" style="background-color: #CCE4E9">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let content of acts">
            <td style="font-size: 14px;" *ngIf="content.status == 2;">{{content.description}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="addToSummary" class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" style="color: #FFFFFF;"
                    (click)="addToSummary()">grade</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

addToSummary(){
  document.getElementById("addToSummary").style.color = "#3DA2DA";

}
```

[image: screenshot]

What do I need to do to change just one of it?

Comment: Within the ngfor all of your button ids are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You current solution does not work because `getElementById` only returns a single (the first found) element with the given id. Besides this performing such DOM queries is definitely not the Angular way.

Instead you would need to change your button definition to something like this:

```
<button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" [style.color]="content.isSelected ? '#3DA2DA' : 'FFFFFF'" (click)="addToSummary(content)">grade</button>
```

And we also change our `addToSummary` method to look like this:

```
addToSummary(content){
    content.isSelected = true;
}
```

So the basic idea is like this:

- Each elements in your `acts` array has an `isSelected` property
- If this property is set to true the star is colored blue
- In the `addToSummary` method we set the `isSelected` property to true
- We handle this the 'Angular way' by using `[style.color]` which allows us to define a simple expression to toggle between white and blue color.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it worked perfectly. Another question, is there a way to "unselect" it? meaning the color of the icon reverts back to the previous colour.

Comment: In your `addToSummary` method simply do: `content.isSelected = !content.isSelected`. This will flip the boolean value from true to false and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this way

```
 <table class="table table-borderless" style="background-color: #CCE4E9">
   <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let content of acts; let i = index;">
           <td style="font-size: 14px;" *ngIf="content.status == 2;"> 
              {{content.description}}
           </td>
           <td>
               <button id="addToSummary" [ngClass]="['addToSummary', i]" class="mdc-icon-button material-icons" style="color: #FFFFFF;"
                (click)="addToSummary(i)">grade</button>
           </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

addToSummary(i){
     let className = "addToSummary " + i;
     document.getElementByClassName(className).style.color = "#3DA2DA";
}
```

Comment: Personally I would advise against any use of `document.getElementBy...` methods in Angular. Angular is perfectly capable of handling OP's question without using these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Renderer can be used to manipulate the DOM

```
import { ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

addToSummary() {
    let elm = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#addToSummary');
    this.renderer.setStyle(elm, 'color', '#3DA2DA');
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Using query selectors really should be a last ditch effort when working with Angular. OP's question is a classical problem Angular can solve without needing any query selectors.